# How to archive multiple folders under one folder using Ansible

Tags: ansible, archive

I'm using the below ansible-playbook code to archive multiple folders under IBM folder.

Below is my absolute path Directory structure:

```
/app
   |-- /IBM
          |--/test
          |--/log
          |--/common
          |--/api
```

I wish to build an archive (gz) that has only IBM folder containing only `common` and `api` folders.

Thus, I wrote the below playbook:

```
- name: Creating the archive
  archive:
    path: 
    - /was/IBM/common
    - /was/IBM/api
    dest: /var/backup/mysetup.tar.gz
    exclude_path:
    - /was/IBM/log
    - /was/IBM/test
    format: gz
```

This gives me the file `mysetup.tar.gz`.

I want the `mysetup.tar.gz` file to have a folder called IBM which should have two folders common and api. Thus, I'm expecting  the below in the `mysetup.tar.gz`

```
IBM
  |--/common
  |--/api
```

But, the `mysetup.tar.gz` has no IBM folder but only the `common` and `api` folders.

Can you please guide me as to how I can get the archive to have both the folders inside the IBM folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include whole IBM folder and then exclude paths you do not want

```
- name: Creating the archive
  archive:
    path: 
    - /was/IBM
    dest: /var/backup/mysetup.tar.gz
    exclude_path:
    - /was/IBM/log
    - /was/IBM/test
    format: gz
```

Comment: What if there are several other folders inside IBM and I'm not sure of excluding all of them as they are created by random users? Thus, my requirement is 1. to exclude specific folders that I know I dont need 2. To include a couple of folders inside IBM that i definitely need. Now, there could be other folders under IBM but I do not need them in my archieve.