# Archive multiple folders under a single folder using Ansible

Tags: ansible, gzip, archive

I'm using the below ansible-playbook code to archive multiple folders under IBM folder.

Below is my absolute path Directory structure:

```
/app
   |-- /IBM
          |--/test
          |--/log
          |--/common
          |--/api
          |--/<unknown folders>
```

The number of folders and files under `IBM folder` is unknown hence it seems impossible to specify all the files / folders under IBM under `exclude_path` attribute.

I wish to build an archive (gz) that has only IBM folder containing only two folders i.e `common` and `api` folders while ignoring the rest of the folders and files.

Thus, I wrote the below playbook:

```
- name: Creating the archive
  archive:
    path: 
    - /was/IBM/common
    - /was/IBM/api
    dest: /var/backup/mysetup.tar.gz
    exclude_path:
    - /was/IBM/common/log
    - /was/IBM/api/tmp
    format: gz
```

This gives me the archive file `mysetup.tar.gz`.

I want the `mysetup.tar.gz` file to have a folder called IBM which should have the two folders `common` and `api`. Thus, I'm expecting the below in the mysetup.tar.gz no matter what other files are under the `IBM` folder.

```
IBM
  |--/common
  |--/api
```

But, the mysetup.tar.gz does not have `IBM` folder but has `common` and `api` folders.

I was not specific hence my question did not get answered here: [How to archive multiple folders under one folder using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850333/how-to-archive-multiple-folders-under-one-folder-using-ansible)

Can you please guide me as to how I can get the archive to have both the folders inside the IBM folder inside the `mysetup.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement you have can't be achieved straight using `archive` module. Two specific reasons are listed below:

1. If you specify the `path` say `/app/IBM` then the content of the zip file will have the path after IBM something like `common/`, `api/`. To get IBM as a root directory inside the tar.gz file, you need to specify `path` as `/app`. This brings to the next point about the usage of `exclude_path`.
2. `exclude_path` doesn't work as you would expect. Say, if the `path` is define as `/app` and you want to exclude `/app/IBM/test`, this wouldn't work. `exclude_path` works only with direct sub folder/file of a defined `path` (with wildcard) which means that exclusion of `/app/IBM/test` would work if `path` defined as `/app/IBM/*` but that is not what is expected and brings back the previous point. There is already an [issue reported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34316) on this topic.

So you probably better off using regular tar command using command/shell module.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but i wish the archive module is updated to help meet the requirement.